# Parsing an image using simple DOM

Tags: php, html, simpledom

I want to parse an image from a HTML file using simple dom. I was using regex until now but everyone told me that this is a really bad idea, so I wanted to try dom.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('192.0.0.1/test.html');
var_dump($html);
foreach ($html->find('img') as $image) {
    echo $images->src;
}
?>
```

TEST.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test</p>
    <img src="test.jpg"/>
    <p>test1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting a blank page, and I checked for errorlogs but I don't have any. I followed the tutorials about DOM, did I make a mistake?

Also can I parse the img from a variable that has the HTML code?
What I mean:

```
$string='<p>sdadasd</p> <img src="test.jph/> <p>asdasda</p>';
$html=file_get_hmtl($string);
```

Comment: i have no idea what is that :D

Comment: Please check what the variable $image contains using var_dump($image);

Comment: Images don't have `href`s

Comment: strangely the output changed from blank to this: find('img') as $image) { echo $images->href; var_dump($images); } ?> 
it's like echoing the code after foreach ($html->
:S

Comment: @musa im completly retarted.. i should stop coding after 9 hours of internship. i wanted to parse the src not href :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this (I don't know where you got `file_get_html`, so i don't know what methods that object returns)

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTMLFile("http://127.0.0.1/index.html"); // I don't remember if this accepts streams

$images = $document->getElementsByTagName("img");

foreach($images as $image) {
    //Use the image
}
```

Or if you need complex queries (e.g. img tags with a certain attribute) you could do

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$images = $xpath->query("//img");
```

Comment: im getting this :  Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;127.0.0.1/yolo.html&quot; in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 3